# 'Permission denied' when running snap applications on Ubuntu 16.04 as a LDAP user

Tags: permissions, snap, ldap

Is it possible to run snap applications on Ubuntu 16.04 as a LDAP user?

I always get 'permission denied' and I don't know what to do.

```
$ sudo snap install postman
postman 6.7.1 from Postman, Inc. (postman-inc✓) installed

$ postman
cannot create user data directory: /home/DOMAIN/user/snap/postman/81: Permission denied
```

It happens for an every snap application, not just Postman.

EDIT:

Same for installing with the `--classic` flag.

Comment: Does it also happen if the ldap user's home directory is just /home/<user>? That being said, you should probably post this question in https://forum.snapcraft.io

Comment: I'm not sure if I can check it on my work computer without everything to be broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that actually works.
I've run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
```

and added `/home/DOMAIN` there, then reboot.

Similar answer
 - https://askubuntu.com/a/1156839/912790

Bug at Launchpad
 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1620771

The bug at Laucnhpad is marked as "won't fix", so maybe this workaround should work for a while.

Comment: What is this `apparmor` ?