# E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

```
sean@sean-mcmahon:~$  sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So update complete, now install

```
sean@sean-mcmahon:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community
sean@sean-mcmahon:~$
```

I am following this [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install).  Any ideas why it cannot locate the package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to install **Mysql Workbench** Just run this command in terminal

```
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

You are good to go with Mysql Workbench

**For Ubuntu 20.04 or higher version:**

```bash
sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community
```

Happy Ubuntu!

Comment: Now it says "Package mysql-workbench is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-workbench' has no installation candidate"

Comment: This did not work for me on Debian 10, i know this is not for debian but i don't find anywhere else about this, besides ubuntu is generic from Debian

Comment: @HassanDadKhan https://askubuntu.com/a/1362504/1180538

Comment: Doesn't work on ubuntu 20.

Comment: @PandianLe I have updated my answer

Answer (score 9):

```
snap install mysql-workbench-community
```

the problem that all snap packages are sanboxed and need to get permission to access local files & connect to DB.

[Cannot connect MySQL Workbench to MySQL server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242026/cannot-connect-mysql-workbench-to-mysql-server)

[access files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930437/permission-denied-error-when-running-apps-installed-as-snap-packages-ubuntu-17)

or install [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/) which is more stable.

Answer (score 2):

First

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then

```
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libreadline5 mariadb-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gdal-data libaec0 libarmadillo8 ... etc.
```

So it looks like community should not have been in the install statement

Answer (score 2):

At the time of my wrinting it seems that only a snap version is available:

sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community

Comment: Hi karel, there is outdated information. apt install mysql-workbench and apt install mysql-workbench-community do -not- work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when using the native mysql repo which is there by default.

Rather, according to the same [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install) referred in question, download the `.deb` package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

and then after installing using the instructions you can install workbench using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

assuming you didn't touched the defaults in the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can install MySQL Workbench by downloading the deb file corresponding to your OS version [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). Check out the archive page for older versions.

Just do `sudo dpkg -i path-to-file/filename.deb`. Even if there are missing dependencies, the output of this command will specify the packages that need to be installed (and you can install them with `sudo apt install package-name`).

**Note**: There are 2 deb files for every OS version - one is `mysql-workbench-community` (which is what you need, I guess) and the other is `mysql-workbench-community-dbgsym`. I think you cannot install the latter without the former.

Comment: This didn't work for Ubuntu 20.04.
Maybe snap is the only option ?