# Cannot connect MySQL Workbench to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, snap, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL workbench from Snap Store and MySQL server 8.0 using `apt`. The server is running fine and I can access MySQL shell from terminal. But I am having issues connecting the Workbench to the server. I'm getting

> #### Cannot Connect to Database Server
>
> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306:
>
> An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.125" (uid=1000 pid=7944 comm="/snap/mysql-workbench-community/5/usr/bin/mysql- wo" label="snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench- community (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service" member="OpenSession” error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.13" (uid=1000 pid=2044 comm="/usr/bin/gnome- keyring-daemon --daemonize --login" label="unconfined")
>
> Please:
>
> 1 Check that MySQL is running on address localhost
>
> 2 Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
>
> 3 Check the user root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
>
> 4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from

There no field for entering password. It shows two options **store in keychain** and **clear**.  On selecting **store in keychain** it prompts for a password, and I enter the password. But then it shows an error:

> Could not store password: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender ...

Comment: Just about certain that you have the dreaded MySql can't connect with a password. See step 3 on this page.  Try it.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: FYI: MySQL Workbench's Snap package isn't officially maintained by MySQL while the debs are.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 (I like to use latest, but I often can't switch right away because of GPU driver issues) so I can't use an officially-supported deb file right now. They only officially support 20.04 and 21.04 right now. So I tried the snap today, and ran into this.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You have installed MySQLWorkbench as a Snap package. You want to store the database password(s) in the Gnome Passwords & Keys facility.

However, a Snap package is *[sandboxed](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/intro/security)*; it is not by default allowed to access this service. When you choose "Store in keychain" MySQLWorkbench is blocked by AppArmor.

You need to enter a command to allow this package to access the service. The command is:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service :password-manager-service
```

I got this from the discussion at [this site](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,686820,686870#msg-686870).

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 20.10

Comment: this didnt work for me, I had to enter mysql as root and use:<< ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; then it worked. Need to point out that my user had  <<auth_plugin>> activated meaning to enter mysql I had only to type mysql now I need to do mysql -p and enter my password

Comment: but then worked

Comment: I get the error `error: snap "snapd" has no slot named "password-manager"`

Comment: Tiago's solution worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me; although I also had to change the permissions in the Software Center to allow me to access certs.

Comment: this worked beautifully... thanks

Comment: This got me past the error for storing the password. I was able to begin connecting. But then I got an error after about 30 seconds saying `Your connection attempt failed for user 'admin' to the MySQL server at <aws_host>:3306: Unable to connect to localhost`. Strange that it's trying to connect to localhost despite me putting in my AWS RDS database host as the host to connect to.

Comment: I was able to connect. It turns out I forgot to allowlist my IP address. :P My bad. So it looks like for me, just running the snap commands in this answer was enough to get me able to connect using Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: It's worked me thank you brother

Comment: Do I need to do it only once or every time?

Comment: Once should be enough.

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: solved my problem on ubuntu 20.04 - thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much . This command worked fine and resolved the issue!

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks much this worked for me

Comment: @Jos thank you very much struggling all day morning both on Ubuntu 22.04 and Linux Mint 21. Until I arrived to your response. Thank you man. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 40):

1. Go to `Ubuntu Software`.
2. Search for `mysql-workbench` and click on `Mysql Workbench Community`.
3. Click on `Permissions`.
4. Enable `Read, add, change, or remove saved password̀s` and `ssh-keys` (if you are also using ssh keys)

Comment: I think this solution is the easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To make it work I tested a different approach and went to [MySQL Community Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

In there, selected the operating system Ubuntu Linux, version 20.04 (x86, 64-bit) and clicked the Download button. Then, "No thanks, just start my download" and saved it. This is a .deb file that got saved in the Download folder and so, to install it,

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.20-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

After installation is complete, went to Applications, opened it and the AppArmor policy error didn't show up again but couldn't still connect using the root user.

Then, tying to connect with the credentials created in the approach two, it worked just fine

[image: MySQL Workbench connected fine in Ubuntu 20.04]