# Problems after upgrading to 22.04 to 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, snap, apparmor

I've upgraded to 22.04.2 LTS from 22.04 via the update manager and have noticed that many of my apps no longer work. As an example, if I run firefox at the terminal with the command `snap run firefox` then I receive the following error:

```
2023/05/28 16:28:33.122160 cmd_run.go:1046: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/home/omar/snap/firefox/2710": mkdir /home/omar/snap/firefox: permission denied
```

I looked in the `syslog` file and there are a number of `apparmor="DENIED"` warnings coming up.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the previous release up release-upgraded from, the method of release-upgrading (update -manager? do-release-upgrade? something else?), and all release-upgrade errors shown in your logs.

Comment: What do I need to do to get the release-upgrade errors from the logs? `grep release-upgrade /var/log/syslog` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

add non-standard home directory to apparmor's HOMEDIRS variable [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156839/1698042) by this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
```

Comment: I don't see a non-standard home directory here.

Comment: @mook765 The location of home directories can be tuned in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.

With Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and above, you can set home directory locations using sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

Comment: That was definitely not my point. I just don't see a non-standard location in the error message OP posted, thats all.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried that and this didn't resolve the issue after a reboot.

Comment: look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/930437/permission-denied-error-when-running-apps-installed-as-snap-packages-ubuntu-17

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured out what was going wrong. It turns out that the update to 22.04.2 LTS has led to all of the directories and files within my home directory, including itself, having their ownership changed to a user 10001 for some reason. This has meant that my user no longer had the ability to create directories or edit files within my home directory.